# Recaptcha Validation : IOException : Tried all: 1 addresses, but could not connect over HTTPS to server: google.com port: 443

Tags: java, https, recaptcha

I have integrated Recaptcha V2 in a contact form. For server-side validation, I am using below code:

```
private JsonObject validateCaptcha(String secret, String response, String remoteip)
  {
      JsonObject jsonObject = null;
      URLConnection connection = null;
      InputStream is = null;
      String charset = Charset.forName("UTF-8").name();
      String url = "https://google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify";
      try {            
          String query = String.format("secret=%s&response=%s&remoteip=%s", 
          URLEncoder.encode(secret, charset),
          URLEncoder.encode(response, charset),
          URLEncoder.encode(remoteip, charset));

          connection = new URL(url + "?" + query).openConnection();
          is = connection.getInputStream();
          JsonReader rdr = Json.createReader(is);
          jsonObject = rdr.readObject();
      } catch (IOException ex) {
          System.out.println("IOException= "+ex.getMessage());
      }
      finally {
          if (is != null) {
              try {
                  is.close();
              } catch (IOException e) {
                  //cannot do anything here
              }
          }
      }
      return jsonObject;
  }
```

it is throwing an IOException and getting caught in first catch block:
**Tried all: 1 addresses, but could not connect over HTTPS to server: google.com port: 443**

I tried changing the link to:
https://wwww.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify
but again same error. 
I am running from localhost and have added '127.0.0.1' as domain successfully in Recaptcha Admin Console.

What could be the reason for this issue. I know our application is behind a firewall.

Answer (score 2):

I do not see ant error into code. Just verify with networking team, if port 443 is available.